# How can we structure XML files which are linkd with multiple XSDs in a MarkLogic database

Tags: marklogic

I am new to MarkLogic and doing some POC to meet the business requirement of our organization.

**Business requirement  :**

We have around 6000 xml files which are now stored in a FTP server. And then transformed as csv files and after which exposed to PowerBI to create visuals.
We do not own any database(relational or nonrelational). As all files are in xml format, so we plan to use MarkLogic to structure all the data.

There are multiple scheme files available for 1 xml file.

**Assumption and Tried possibilities :**

Template Driven extraction method can be used insert the XML files in Marklogic in form of tabular structure.
I have tried and it works fine for now when there is less content in a xml file.

**Query :**

As we have multiple xsds linked with 1 XML file, so would it be like we have to create multiple views for each of the xsds?

Comment: When you say that you have multiple XSD linked with one XML file, what exactly do you mean? Do you mean that a single XML document could contain multiple types of documents (such as a list or choice, and each of those are different types of documents bound to a different schema), or just that there is an XSD that is comprised of multiple XSD fragments or that it imports many fragments? You can project as many TDE views as you like from a single XML document. If you want to have a view per XSD, that should work just fine.

Comment: There is an XSD which imports many XSD fragments.  How to create template for such XML files created from that main xsd which imports multiple other XSD fragments in it.